# What would be an efficient way to generalize code to encompass dynamic processes?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro that will automate the daily report we generate every morning in our Accounts/Receivables department. The report compares our accounting records (Great Plains) to our itemized bank statement for all received payments.

Up until this point (for the last month) I have been coding this macro to fully create the reconciliation report and notify the user of all discrepancies between the accounts (i.e. if we received $20.00 but it was not recorded, the $20.00 is presented to the user in a `UserForm's ListBox`, containing buttons to remove the amount if it's simply an error, or reflect the amount in the report summary, if it's been taken care of).

After the process was seen, I was asked to format the macro to generate a report for 3 other accounts. I have successfully formatted the calculations and processing of data through generalization of code and parameterization of my methods. My issue comes to the `UserForm`, though.

The `UserForm`'s uses code that directly affects specific variables that are only defined once the Bank Wire report is generated, but since it is no longer the only report, I am unsure how I can have the data reflected through the necessary variables.

Here's the code I am referring to in the `UserForm`:

```
    Private Sub AddedtoGPButton_Click()
        Dim BWItem As Double

        For lItem = BWListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If BWListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
                BWItem = BWListBox.List(lItem, 0)
                BWListBox.RemoveItem lItem
                If BWAddedGPSum2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    BWAddedGPSum2.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    BWAddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    BWAddedGPSum2.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    Set BWAddedGPSum2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -3), BWGPSum.Offset(1, 1))
                    BWAddedGPSum2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                    Set BWAddedGPTitle2 = Range(BWGPSum.Offset(1, -2), BWGPSum.Offset(1, -1))
                    With BWAddedGPTitle2
                        .MergeCells = True
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With
                        BWAddedGPTitle2.Value = "Added to Deposit:"
                    Set BWAddedGPSum2 = BWGPSum.Offset(1, 0)
                        If BWAddedGPSum Is Nothing Then
                            BWAddedGPSum2.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        End If
                    If BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0).Text = "" Then
                        Set BWGPSubtotal = BWGPSum
                        Set BWGPSum = BWVariance.Offset(-2, 0)
                            Range(BWGPSum.Offset(0, -1), BWGPSum.Offset(0, -2)).MergeCells = True
                            BWGPSum.Offset(0, -1).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                            BWGPSum.Offset(0, -2).Value = "Total:"
                            BWGPSum.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    End If
                End If
                BWAddedGPSum2.Value = Format((BWAddedGPSum2.Value + BWItem), "$#,##0.00")
                BWGPSum.Value = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp), _
                                       BWGPSum.Offset(-1, 0)), "$#,##0.00")
                Call DetermineVariance(BWTitle, BWVariance, BWReconciled, BWttl, BWGPSum)
                If Me.BWListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

..

The Variables that are defined within the `UserForm` as objects (`ListBox`, `TextBox`, `Label`, etc.) are:

BWItem as Double and BWListBox.

The Variables that are established in the main module are:

BWAddedGPSum2 as Range, BWGPSum as Range, BWAddedGPTitle2 as Range, and DetermineVariance as a method.

..

Here is a screenshot of the initial (pre-report) `UserForm`, enabling you to see how the report's data originates, as well as a second screenshot displaying the `UserForm` in question (the `UserForm` that contains the discrepancies):

[image: Initial <code>UserForm</code>]

[image: Problematic <code>UserForm</code>]

..

My main issue is when I try to highlight the item and select the `AddedToGPButton`, it's attempting to apply the event to the variables listed in the code block above. As I previously mentioned, it works beautifully for the Bank Wire report, but now that I'm trying to generalize, it's causing a huge pain in the neck that I'm not even sure how to go about. What would be an efficient and effective way to generalize the code to get the same outcome?

As you can see in the above screenshots, the report for the **Bank Wires** has already been generated. The line titled "*Added to Deposit:*" is what occurs when you highlight an item and press the Added to GP button. When you attempt to do the same with the Credit Cards report, it cannot find the variable for the Credit Cards, because as you can see, it's formatted for Wires.

Comment: I'm having a slow moment: can you pinpoint for me which parts of your code are formatted for Wires and why you're having trouble converting them/adding an If/Then/Else branch for them?

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 I apologize, the variable names may be confusing since, as I mentioned, it was supposed to be only for one report. The BWListBox is the listbox on the right side, and the buttonEvent listed is for the right button captioned "Added to GP". The range, `BWAddedGPSum2` is a range that is defined in the main module ONLY WHEN the Bank Wire report checkbox = true and the report is ran, otherwise it is null. How could I transpose this variable with another for universal input to be processed? The result of this button is seen in the cell E12, next to the cell.value = "Added to Deposit".

Comment: I'm probably failing to understand you, but in response to your question "How could I transpose this variable with another for universal input to be calculated?", couldn't you check to see if each of the similar variables for the different reports (`BWAddedGPSum2`, `CCAddedGPSum2`, etc.) is null and then generate the "Added to Deposit" numbers you want?

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 That's the trick... The macro's `checkboxes` enable the user to run just one or multiple reports. If the user runs a Wire Report and a Credit Card Report at the same time then the BWVariables will not be null and will cause the wrong data to be attributed to the wrong variables.

Comment: Although, I was looking into the possibility of setting the Userform to an object and running each report would only alter the respective instance of the UserForm. I'm not entirely sure if this is possible though. Such as `Dim BWForm = new UnmatchedSummary`, `Dim CCForm = new UnmatchedSummary`... `CCForm.miscValues = CC_Collection`, `BWForm.miscValues = BW_Collection`. 1.) I'm not even sure if this is possible. 2.) My searches haven't proved to be fruitful, mainly because I'm not sure if this has a technical term

Comment: How would you tell in human, rather than programmatic, terms which report you want to generate the "Added to Deposit" field for? Is the Credit Card report higher priority than the Bank Wire report? Do you want it to depend on where the "Unmatched Summary" box is currently located? Do you want it to generate "Added to Deposit" numbers for all reports that don't already have them?

Comment: While you might feel inclined to continue this discussion in order to work out the essence of this question, I'd like to add that this question seems better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity including best-practices. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 The unmatched summary pictured contains data only for the CC Report. This is taking data from the balancing process within the code only dealing with C.C.s... So I want it to automatically use the variables that are associated with the balance that the UserForm is currently displaying information for, since the form only displays IF there is a discrepancy in the balancing process... If one report doesn't have a discrepancy, I don't want it to drop it in the Check Report just because the variable hasn't been utilized yet. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @Ralph Thank you for your suggestion! I often forget there is a section for that in particular since almost all of my code is broken from the start. I will move this on over soon

Comment: @Ralph I would have assumed so also from the question title, but after reading the question it seems obvious to me that Munkeeface doesn't have code that does exactly what he wants already yet - I think that largely disqualifies a migration, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Munkeeface What you said makes sense. Looking at the formatting in the picture, would it make sense to detect the report type from the report name field in row 3, 3 columns to the left of the data detected as having a discrepancy, and then use appropriate variables from there? Would it work to create a set of variables for each requested report in the userform, then detect which report type's imbalance is currently being dealt with in the Unmatched Summary box and then refer to the appropriate set of userform variables?

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 Well, the way it works at the moment is the UserForm's showModal = false, allowing the user to navigate the worksheets to analyze the data to investigate the discrepancy. With this said, I'm not sure how to set the rest of the macro to pause until the mode is closed, which is only me.hide, instead of a termination. I prefer not to use a termination event to call further modules, so I can keep all called Subs visible within the main sub. This said,  It's hard to set the discrepancy data to move to the next set without making it modal, removing the user's ability to navigate.

Comment: Oh, I know exactly what you mean there. Would it be best to rework your Unmatched Summary code to both be explicit about which report it belongs to and also to navigate to the sheet it is pulling the data from? That would also allow you to identify the report based upon the name as I suggested one comment above and to use the appropriate data from your report-selecting userform.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 While this would work extremely well for most other workbooks, this workbook copies the original files (raw data) and pastes it into a new sheet, titled to reflect which source data it contains. Unfortunately almost all of these sheets has 400+ rows of data (and I prefer not to modify the source data for authenticity), leaving the rest of the sheet out of the visible scope if I make the form modal and just leave the sheet visible in the background. Yes, I plan to implement your previous comment soon, I just have to squash other bugs that are preventing me from reaching that step

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 The workbook will contain at minimum 13 sheets... If it's reporting for a weekend, it could take up to 18 sheets

Comment: @Munkeeface Sounds good. I don't have any further suggestions for your question. Good luck with your work!